# Backbone.js Collections not applying Models (using Code Igniter)

Tags: codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

I'm attempting to develop a site using CodeIgniter and Backbone.js, but I'm running into an issue when attempting to set Models to a Collection I have called fetch() on.  I am using the REST API by Phil Sturgeon, and am receiving a JSON response when using fetch() on the Collection, but no children Models are added to it.

Here's the javascript I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    window.People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Person,
        url: "/api/content/users/format/json"
    });
});
```

And my CI Controller:

```
require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class Content extends REST_Controller   {    
    function users_get()    {       
        $users = array(
            array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Some Guy', 'email' => 'example1@example.com'),
            array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Person Face', 'email' => 'example2@example.com')
    );

        if($users) {
            $this->response($users, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
        } else {
            $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any users!'), 404);
        }
    }
}
```

And when attempting to fetch() the Models for the Collection via the console like:

```
peoples = new People();
peoples.fetch();
peoples.models;
```

It gets the JSON response, but still says 'There are no child objects' (see image):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5vZv.png

Any idea what is going wrong?  Totally stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explications

It's normal that `people.models` is empty **directly** after the fetch() call, you need to wait the end of the ajax request.

Indeed, `fetch()` is **asynchronous** and the Backbone JS documention says :

> **collection.fetch([options])**
>
> [...] The options hash takes success and error callbacks which will be passed (collection, response) as arguments.

Source: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch

### Solution

You need to use :

```
peoples = new People();
peoples.fetch({
    success: function (collection, response) {
        // The collection is filled
        console.log('Models : ', peoples.models);
    }
});
```