# How do I bind an event to a model that isn't loaded yet?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I've got a pretty simple backbone app with a model, a collection, and a couple of views.  I'm fetching the actual data from the server by doing a collection.fetch() at page load.

My problem is that one of my views is a "detail" view, and I want to bind it to a particular model - but I don't have the model yet when the page loads.  My code looks a lot like this:

```
window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Routers: {}
}

App.Models.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/people'
});

App.Collections.People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Person,
    url: '/api/people'
});

people = new App.Collections.People()

App.Views.List = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render());
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html("We've got " + this.collection.length + " models." )
    }
});

listView = new App.Views.List({collection: people})

App.Views.Detail = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('change', this.render());
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html("Model goes here!")
    }
});

App.Routers.Main = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '/people': 'list',
        '/people/:id': 'detail'
    },
    list: function() {
        listView.render();
    },
    detail: function(id) {
        detailView = new App.Views.Detail({model: people.get(id)})
        detailView.render()
    }
})

main = new App.Routers.Main();
Backbone.history.start();
people.fetch();
```

But if I start with the detail route active, the `people` collection is empty, so `people.get(id)` doesn't return anything, so my new view has `this.model` undefined, and won't let me bind any events relating to it.  The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined
```

If I start with the list route active, then by the time I click on an item to bring up the detail view `people` is populated, so everything works.

What's the right way to bind model-related events for a "detail" view when you're fetching the data after page load?

Answer (score 1):

You have a part of the answer here: [Backbone.js Collections not applying Models (using Code Igniter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662808/backbone-js-collections-not-applying-models-using-code-igniter/8666317#8666317)

Indeed, you need to wait that `people.fetch` finishes its ajax request before to call `Backbone.history.start();` and trigger the actual route.

Your code should look like:

```
// [...]
main = new App.Routers.Main();
peoples.fetch({
    success: function (collection, response) {
        // The collection is filled, trigger the route
        Backbone.history.start();
    }
});
```

*You can add a loader on the page and hide it when the collection is loaded.*